# How to make a table borders animation with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, animation, border, css-tables

I would like to create a Javascript function that will display the borders of a table in html like in the video [here.](http://youtu.be/-vmI0w6LWAU)
*(Since we can't post videos here, I uploaded the video on YouTube. Please watch it. It's only 5 sec.)*
I mean when the body/page loads, the table borders will appear in this way.
I do not have any idea how to do this. Can anybody please give me a help coding this animation?

Comment: I can't watch it, its private.

Comment: "This video is private."

Comment: Ok I fixed it. It's now public

Comment: You might be able to recreate something more easily by using CSS transformations by stretching an image or something along those lines.

Comment: I can't watch.. is private.. but... you can try use jquery `$(document).ready(function(){ $('#table').css('border', '1px solid'); });` or using js.. you can try add (end of page) a `<script>document.getElementById('tableid').style.border = "1px solid"</script>`

Comment: @HugoS.Mendes I removed the privacy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting question. I would try to fake border using `:after` pseudo-element and CSS animations. Take a look at this demo.

```
table:after {
    content: '';
    z-index: -1;
    position: absolute;
    top: -3px;
    left: -3px;
    bottom: 100%;
    right: 100%;
    background: green;
    -webkit-animation-name: border;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 3s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: lenear;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes border {
    from {
        top: -3px;
        top: -3px;
    }
    to {
        bottom: -4px;
        right: -4px;
    }
}
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/dfsq/uSmL3/

As alternative to CSS animations you can use some element (i.e. div), position it properly under the table and animate its width and height wiht javascript.

Comment: Niiiiice !!!! Until now, your answer is the best. but I wanna wait for any other/better suggestions :)

Comment: Ok. It seems that nobody have an answer except you so I will take your code but can I modify it a lit bit? Can you make the border displays in the same way as you made it but from the 2 opposing corners in the same time? I mean from the upper left and the lower right corners? thanks again